# Wordpress loop inside of function = fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress, scope

I have my Wordpress blog on blog.mysite.com, and a totally different site (built in my framework) at www.mysite.com.

I know if the blog and another site are on the same server, and have correct permissions, I can use the following to "syndicate" my blogs to the non-blog site with:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/var/www/vhosts/mysite/subdomains/blog/httpdocs/wp-config.php');
query_posts('showposts=5');
```

...and then run a loop on the page.

The problem is that since my non-blog site is a framework, everything except for my front controller lives in a function - and this is creating the following error for me:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   stdClass::set_prefix()

(btw, I'm fairly certain the fact that this code is called within a function that is causing the error...when I put the code on the front controller (not in function), the error disappears)

I would REALLY like to have recent blog listings on my non-blog site to spruce it up. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You'll need to show the code that causes the error.

Comment: pekka...the above code starting with define causes the error when put in my page's controller. when its on the front controller (before the page controller or models are called), it doesn't cause an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess you forgot to write

```
global $wpdb
```

inside the function